# How do you find the dream job of a bitzen?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

The dream job is showing as "???"...   How do I find out the Bitzen's dream job?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They show up as that when you don't have the floor that their dream job is on. If you have the floor that their job is on, it will say the name of the floor instead of the question marks.